# Как правильно сделать сравнение (область видимости)

Tags: c#, область-видимости

Ребят, запуталась с областью видимости. ПОмогите разобраться.
Есть запрос в базу данных, оно находит число "012" или "018". Если одно число то в результат newn надо подставить строку "ПС" иначе ПН. Но если таким образом делать то область видимости не позволяет обратиться к typeOfN. Как правильно сделать сравнение и добавить в результат?!

```
public static class _New
{
    public static string Newn()
    {
         const int t = 012;
         var tempTypeN = SqlClient.Main.CreateCommand(string.Format("SELECT NEW FROM NEWT WHERE new = @new ", new SqlParam("new", doc.new))).ExecNonQuery();
            if (tempTypeN != t)
            {
                var typeOfN = "ПС";
            }
            else
            {
                var typeOfN = "ПН";
            }

            var newn = typeOfN;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string newn = null;
if (tempTypeN != t)
{
    newn = "ПС";
}
else
{
    newn = "ПН";
}

Console.WriteLine(newn); //пример...
```

То есть сначала создаем пустую переменную с известным типом, а потом уже ее заполняем где нам необходимо.